# Exception from Stored Procedure not caught in .NET using SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)

Tags: vb.net, exception, sql-server-2012, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

I have a Stored Procedure that I am executing from VB.NET. The SP should insert records into a table and return a set to the calling app. The set returned are the records that were inserted.

If the `INSERT` fails, the exception is caught and re-thrown in the SP, but I never see the exception in my application. The severity level is 14, so I should see it.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN TRY    

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

        -- Declare local variables
        DECLARE @DefaultCategoryID AS BIGINT = 1                -- 1 = 'Default Category' (which means no category)
        DECLARE @DefaultWeight AS DECIMAL(18,6) = 0
        DECLARE @InsertionDate AS DATETIME2(7) = GETDATE()
        DECLARE @SendToWebsite AS BIT = 0                       -- 0 = 'NO'
        DECLARE @MagentoPartTypeID AS BIGINT = 1                -- For now, this is the only part type we are importing from COPICS ('simple' part type)

        DECLARE @NotUploaded_PartStatusID AS TINYINT = 0        -- 0 = 'Not Uploaded'
        DECLARE @Enabled_PartStatusID AS TINYINT = 1            -- 1 = 'Enabled'
        DECLARE @Disabled_PartStatusID AS TINYINT = 2           -- 2 = 'Disabled'


        -- Get the part numbers that will be inserted (this set will be returned to calling procedure).
        SELECT c.PartNumber
        FROM
            COPICSPartFile c 
            LEFT JOIN Part p on c.PartNumber = p.PartNumber
        WHERE 
            p.PartNumber IS NULL        

        -- Insert new records from COPICSPartFile (records that don't exist - by PartNumber - in Part table)
        INSERT INTO Part
            ([PartNumber]
            ,[ReplacementPartNumber]
            ,[ShortDescription]
            ,[ListPrice]
            ,[PartStatusTypeID]
            ,[Weight]
            ,[CategoryID]
            ,[DateInserted]
            ,[SendToWebsite]
            ,[FileName]
            ,[MagentoPartTypeID]
            ,[PrintNumber])
        SELECT
            c.PartNumber
            ,c.ReplacementPartNumber
            ,c.ShortDescription
            ,c.ListPrice
            ,CASE WHEN c.PartStatusTypeID = @Enabled_PartStatusID THEN @NotUploaded_PartStatusID ELSE @Disabled_PartStatusID END
            ,@DefaultWeight
            ,@DefaultCategoryID
            ,@InsertionDate
            ,@SendToWebsite
            ,@FileName
            ,@MagentoPartTypeID
            ,c.PrintNumber
        FROM
            COPICSPartFile c 
            LEFT JOIN Part p on c.PartNumber = p.PartNumber
        WHERE 
            p.PartNumber IS NULL


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;

END CATCH
```

And here is the .net code:

```
Try

    'Create command
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    conn = New SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString)
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandText = "trxInsertPartFromCOPICSPartFile"
    With command.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName)
    End With
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return dt
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

Catch ex As SqlException

    Dim myMessage As String = ex.Message

Finally
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

As I was trying to figure out why the exception (duplicate key) wasn't being caught in my application, I tried commenting out the `SELECT` statement in the SP just before the `INSERT` and voila. The exception from the `INSERT` is caught in the application.

Can someone explain to me why the `SELECT` statement causes this? I know I can break out the `SELECT` into another SP, but I'd like to keep it all one atomic transaction if possible. Is this expected behavior? Is there a way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say not seeing the exception in your application are you referring to in the UI or log? Or are you saying a breakpoint doesn't get hit? You aren't actually doing anything with the exception. You are throwing it away.

Comment: @TyCobb - I am setting a breakpoint there and it's not being hit when I debug. Originally, I was letting the exception bubble up to another method and handling it there. Just added the catch there for easier debugging.

Comment: It is probably being "eaten" by the `Fill` method. How about creating a SqlDataReader, doing a `command.ExecuteReader()` and using the reader to populate the `DataTable` via `Load()`? This way the error should occur in the `ExecuteReader()` and should be catchable. **OR** maybe it is no longer a `SqlException` coming out of `Fill`, so just catch a generic `Exception`.

Comment: Thanks @srutzky - using the ExecuteReader() with Load() fixed the issue. The exception was thrown on the Load() statement.

Comment: So... guess it was more of an issue in how I was handling the result from my stored procedure call rather than how I wrote the stored procedure...? I've been using DataTable.Fill() for years and never seen this before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being swallowed by the `Fill` method. Instead of using that method, create a `SqlDataReader`, do a `command.ExecuteReader()`, and then use the reader to populate the `DataTable` via `Load()`. This way the error should occur in the `ExecuteReader()` method and should be catchable. And then you shouldn't need the `SqlDataAdapter`.

```
Try
    'Create command
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    conn = New SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString)
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandText = "trxInsertPartFromCOPICSPartFile"
    With command.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName)
    End With

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    dt.Load(reader)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return dt
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

Catch ex As SqlException

    Dim myMessage As String = ex.Message

Finally
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

Also, you might be better off on several levels if you combine the SELECT and the INSERT into a single statement. You can do this via the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO Part
        ([PartNumber]
        ,[ReplacementPartNumber]
        ,[ShortDescription]
        ,[ListPrice]
        ,[PartStatusTypeID]
        ,[Weight]
        ,[CategoryID]
        ,[DateInserted]
        ,[SendToWebsite]
        ,[FileName]
        ,[MagentoPartTypeID]
        ,[PrintNumber])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[PartNumber] -- return the inserted values to the app code
    SELECT
        c.PartNumber
        ,c.ReplacementPartNumber
        ,c.ShortDescription
        ,c.ListPrice
        ,CASE WHEN c.PartStatusTypeID = @Enabled_PartStatusID
                THEN @NotUploaded_PartStatusID
                ELSE @Disabled_PartStatusID END
        ,@DefaultWeight
        ,@DefaultCategoryID
        ,@InsertionDate
        ,@SendToWebsite
        ,@FileName
        ,@MagentoPartTypeID
        ,c.PrintNumber
    FROM
        COPICSPartFile c 
        LEFT JOIN Part p on c.PartNumber = p.PartNumber
    WHERE 
        p.PartNumber IS NULL
```

Comment: This is certainly a cleaner way to write the SQL, but didn't solve the issue. Thanks, though! I didn't know I had access to the INSERTED table like this.

Comment: @TrailJon Thanks for adding the working code. I cleaned up the wording of the suggested fix and removed the `SqlDataAdapter` from the code as it is no longer needed. Also, I put in a link to the `OUTPUT` documentation that you should check out. It is a _very_ cool feature that was introduced in SQL Server 2005 and gives you access to both `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables :).